# Finding max date difference on a single column

Tags: sql-server, datetime

in the below table example - Table A, we have entries for four different ID's 1,2,3,4 with the respective status and its time. I wanted to find the "ID" which took the maximum amount of time to change the "Status" from Started to Completed. In the below example it is ID = 4. I wanted to run a query and find the results, where we currently has approximately million records in a table. It would be really great, if someone provide an effective way to retrieve this data.

Table A

```
ID    Status         Date(YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS)
1.    Started        2017-01-01 01:00:00
1.    Completed      2017-01-01 02:00:00
2.    Started        2017-10-02 03:00:00
2.    Completed      2017-10-02 05:00:00
3.    Started        2017-15-03 06:00:00
3.    Completed      2017-15-03 09:00:00
4.    Started        2017-22-04 10:00:00
4.    Completed      2017-22-04 15:00:00
```

Thanks!
Bruce

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag the one you are using.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide your code.

Comment: I was actually running different queries. select * from table where status = 'completed' order by Date desc. And then took some recent ID's which is in 'completed' status. select Date from table where ID in (1,2,3,4) and was checking manually the maximum difference between date for each given ID. Was wondering if I can write a subquery or self join to retrieve the records, since I currently have 1 million records on the table and it is hard to check for each record manually. Your help would be much appreicated. Thanks!

Comment: Can `ID` have multiple `Started` and `Completed` statuses? or one `ID` have just one  `Started` and just one `Completed` ?

Comment: ID will have only one Started Status and may have multiple Completed statuses. Thanks!

Comment: Then which date difference do you want, from `Started` to first `Completed`, or from  `Started` to last  `Completed`  ?

Comment: Started to LAST Completed

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below:

```
Select top 1 with ties Id from #yourDate y1
    join #yourDate y2
On y1.Id = y2.Id
    and y1.[STatus] = 'Started'
    and y2.[STatus] = 'Completed'
    order by Row_number() over(order by  datediff(mi,y1.[Date], y2.[date]) desc)
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run this sql but it may solve your problem.

```
select  a.id, max(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.date, b.date + 1)) from TableA as a 
join TableA as b on a.id = b.id
where a.status="started" and b.status="completed"
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    started.ID, timediff(completed.date, started.date) as elapsed_time
FROM TABLE_A as started
INNER JOIN TABLE_A as completed ON (completed.ID=started.ID AND completed.status='Completed')
WHERE started.status='Started'
ORDER BY elapsed_time desc
```

be sure there's a index on TABLE_A for the columns ID, date

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with a correlated sub-query. Just uncomment the `TOP 1` to get ID 4 in this case. This is based off your comments that there is only 1 "started" record, but could be multiple "completed" records for each ID.

```
declare @TableA table (ID int, Status varchar(64), Date datetime)
insert into @TableA
values
(1,'Started','2017-01-01 01:00:00'),
(1,'Completed','2017-01-01 02:00:00'),
(2,'Started','2017-02-10 03:00:00'),
(2,'Completed','2017-02-10 05:00:00'),
(3,'Started','2017-03-15 06:00:00'),
(3,'Completed','2017-03-15 09:00:00'),
(4,'Started','2017-04-22 10:00:00'),
(4,'Completed','2017-04-22 15:00:00')


select --top 1
    s.ID
    ,datediff(minute,s.Date,e.EndDate) as TimeDifference
from @TableA s
inner join(
    select
        ID
        ,max(Date) as EndDate
    from @TableA
    where Status = 'Completed'
    group by ID) e on e.ID = s.ID
where
    s.Status = 'Started'
order by
    datediff(minute,s.Date,e.EndDate)  desc
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+----------------+
| ID | TimeDifference |
+----+----------------+
|  4 |            300 |
|  3 |            180 |
|  2 |            120 |
|  1 |             60 |
+----+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank a lot for providing the details. This really worked! Appreciate your time and help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that 'started' will always be the earliest point in time for each ID and the last 'completed' record you are considering will always be the latest point in time for each ID, the following should have good performance for a large number of records:

```
SELECT TOP 1
      id
    , DATEDIFF(s, MIN([Date]), MAX([date])) AS Elapsed
FROM   @TableA
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(s, MIN([Date]), MAX([date])) DESC
```

Comment: This is working much faster. Thanks for your valuable inputs!